# Need help working with Phonegap (Cordova actually)

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I've being working with Node.js and Angular.js. But now I am moving into mobile (Android) and I would like to solve some doubts before getting started because documentations have being quite confusing. So here are my questions:

- How will the mobile app connect to the backend? is it just configuring the config.xml file?
- How is the Login system suppose to work when talking from the mobile to the backend?
- Does the Login system allow to use the Notification API's? Which variables should I consider?
- What limitations would I have when working with Javascript? Like Underscore, D3, Three.js, etc...

If anyone could answer these questions I would really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) It depends on what you refer as "back-end". I assume you re referring to some remote server connection. As Cordova is fully based on HTML,CSS and Javascript, you can use some ajax calls to connect to your server(back-end) to get/put data.

2) For my apps, for login system, I use ajax based solution to callback my remote server and validate the login username and password.

3) Yes. You can use the features of Alert, Beep, Vibrate and even push notifications. Refer to the corresponding API docs.

4) Virtually no limitations on what use as long as its javascript and does not create contention with other javascript codes you use together.

Answer (score 0):

It will connect to the backend the same way your web apps do, what transports do you usually use?

Logins will work the same way your web apps do.

There are no limitations on javascript, it will be very similar to developing for the mobile web except you will have more device APIs available to you and you will have the ability to create custom device APIs.